# Cocos 2d application structure

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d and want to know some thing about the cocos2d application structure.
Here is code in appdidfinishlaunching function in the default template.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    // Init the window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Try to use CADisplayLink director
    // if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    //
    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //
    //
    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
//  if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
//      CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    //
    // VERY IMPORTANT:
    // If the rotation is going to be controlled by a UIViewController
    // then the device orientation should be "Portrait".
    //
    // IMPORTANT:
    // By default, this template only supports Landscape orientations.
    // Edit the RootViewController.m file to edit the supported orientations.
    //
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif

    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];


    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [viewController setView:glView];

    // make the View Controller a child of the main window
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];


    // Removes the startup flicker
    [self removeStartupFlicker];

    // Run the intro Scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [HelloWorld scene]];     
}
```

My question is when we add some child to CCDirector how this thing can be shown on the screen when CCDirector director is never added on the window.view
we have the following lines of code

// make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [viewController setView:glView];

This will set the view of RootViewController to glView and before that we are setting

[director setOpenGLView:glView];
means openglView of director is set to glView.

Do we dont have to add the director to the viewcontroller assuming the it can be added so that whatever we add something to the Director it will be visible on the screen.

My question is that how the scene should be visible on the iphone screen when we have never added CCDirector on the RootViewController.

Answer (score 1):

CCDirector is setting glView as a view of RootViewController. All next drawing is made using opengl. In the glView. So cocos2d classes like CCLayer, CCNode, CCSprite and so on have nothing with UIView or UIViewController